# Minimal Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A minimal dependence means that $\sum_{i=1}^ma_iv_i = 0$ where vectors $v_i \in S$ are distinct, not all of $a_i$s are zero, $m \geq 1$ is as small as possible.

I was asked to show that if both $\sum_{i=1}^ma_iv_i = 0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^mb_iv_i = 0$ are minimal dependence, then $a_i=cb_i$ where $c$ is a scalar.

It seems easy, but I'm only able to write that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m(b_i-a_i)v_i = 0.
$$

If I know that the $v_i$s are linearly independent, then it's easy (simply $b_i = a_i$), but the problem is that I don't, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The $v_i$s are not linearly independant, but each proper subfamily of the $v_i$s is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ you can consider the following sum:

$\sum_{k=1}^m(b_k-\lambda a_k)v_k=$

$=\sum_{k=1}^n b_kv_k+\lambda\sum_{k=1}^ma_kv_k =0+0=0$

Without lost of generality we can assume that $a_m\neq 0$, so if you choose $\lambda:=\frac{b_m}{a_m}$ then

$b_m-\lambda a_m=0$ so

$\sum_{k=1}^m(b_k-\lambda a_k)v_k= \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(b_k-\lambda a_k)v_k=0$

but $m$ is minimal, so you must have that

$b_k-\lambda a_k=0$ for each $k=1,\dots , m$ that means

$b_k=\lambda a_k$

Your costant $c$ is $\lambda=\frac{b_m}{a_m}$

Comment: but i think that you only proved that "it can be $b_k=\lambda a_k$" not "it has to be $b_k=\lambda a_k$"

Comment: because your argument sits on the fact that you chose $\lambda = \frac{b_m}{a_m}$

Comment: But in general you can choose also \lambda=b_j/a_j for same j such that $a_j\neq 0$. I don’t understand your question sorry

Comment: oh never mind i got it thank you！